# Сравнение объектов методом equals - переопределение и перегрузка. Ошибка компиляции

Tags: java

При сравнении объектов нужно **переопределять** метод equals, но не **перегружать**. Пытаюсь сделать именно так, но компилятор говорит **Cannot resolve symbol 'dnaCode'** Подскажите пожалуйста в чём причина?

Если метод equals перегружать - компилируется нормально, вот такой код:

```
 public static class Man {
    int dnaCode; //поле класса по которому нужно сравнивать

    public boolean equals(Man man) { //перегрузка метода
        return this.dnaCode == man.dnaCode; //это компилируется нормально
    }
```

Если метод equals переопределять - не компилируется:

```
public static class Man {
    int dnaCode;

    public boolean equals(Object man) { //переопределение метода
        return this.dnaCode == man.dnaCode; //возле красного dnaCode спойлер Cannot resolve symbol 'dnaCode'
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переопределить метод, изменив его параметры нельзя, но вы можете сделать вот так:

```
public static class Man {
int dnaCode;

public boolean equals(Object man) { //переопределение метода
    if(man instanceof Man) // Проверка на принадлежность к Man
        return this.dnaCode == ((Man)man).dnaCode; //приведение Object к Man
    return false; // Если man не является Man
}
```

Comment: Да, так компилируется. Если можно подскажите ещё - если будет сравнение строковое, а не числовое, то эта строка return this.dnaCode == ((Man)man).dnaCode; тоже буде содержать ==   или что-то другое?

Comment: @ИгорьГор Не очень понял про "будет содержать ==", но строковое сравнение выполняется методом String.equals `return this.dnaCode.equals(((Man)man).dnaCode)`, при условии что оба dnaCode строки.

Comment: Вы верно поняли, что я имел ввиду. Меня смущает, что мы переопределяем метод equals и тут же в нём используем equals.

Comment: @ИгорьГор Если всё оставить как есть (dnaCode - int), то его нужно конвертировать в строку `return String.valueOf(dnaCode).equals( String.valueOf( ((Man)man).dnaCode ) );`

Comment: Не получается в комментарии вставлять <код>. Как это делается?

Comment: @ИгорьГор Код вставляется между двумя '

Answer (score 1):

Есть типичная реализация метода equals:

- сначала выполняются три быстрые проверки на сравнение ссылок
- потом объект из параметра кастуется до нужного типа и выполняются уже необходимые проверки по полям

  ```
  @Override

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
      // проверка равенства ссылок на объекты
      if (this == o) return true;
      // проверка что объект в параметре не нулевой
      if (o == null) return false;
      // принадлежность к одному классу
      if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

      // каст к проверяемому классу 
      Man man = (Man) o;

      // проверяем единственное интересующее нас поле
      return dna.equals(man.dna);
  }
  ```

Т.к. `DNA` это скорее всего тоже объект, то сравнивать его с другой `DNA` лучше методом `equals`, переопределенном в классе `DNA`, а не с помощью сравнения ссылок `==`. И не забудьте переопределить методы `hashCode()` у `Man` и `DNA`. Это очень помогает другим классам сравнивать объекты быстро.

**UPD** Не используйте `Instance of` без необходимости.

Проверка с помощью `Instance of` будет возвращать `true` для подклассов, т.е. работать правильно только в случае если ваш класс объявлен как `immutable`. В противном случае нарушается принцип симметрии и `a.equals(b)` возможно даст не такой же результат как  `b.equals(a`). К тому же этот метод медленнее чем `getClass()`.

Comment: Скажите, а в getClass() какой Class имеется ввиду - тот который я собираюсь сравнивать (как в исходном вопросе - это Man)?

Comment: getClass() даст ссылку на класс Man,  а  o.getClass() - на класс объекта из параметра, конечно если мы говорим о переопределении метода equals в классе Man